# Need help using generic type APIResponse class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

My manager told me to use the following class while sending response back from Web pi controller in Asp.net core project, now I am new to programming and confuse how to make instance of it, i can convert it to JSON after. Only the usage of APIResponse class is out of my knowledge.

```
public class APIResponse<T>
{
    public APIResponse()
      : this(default(T))
    {

    }
    public APIResponse(T data)
        : this(ResponseCodes.RESPONSE_OK, ResponseMessages.RESPONSE_OK, data)
    {

    }
    public APIResponse(int _code, string _msg, T _data)
    {
        this.code = _code;
        this.msg = _msg;
        this.data = _data;
    }

    public int code
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string msg
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public T data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int pageCount { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
    public int recordCount { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make object of it and add data in the fields.
Here is the response sample:
[image: Response]

Comment: "Create an instance" just means to call the constructor. Like `new ApiResponse<string>(200, "Some message", "some string")`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but what about the generic object, I actually have to send the response like in the image I just added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class called Data with the following fields:

```
public class Data
    {
        public string status;
        public string statusMessage; 
    }
```

Then you would call the generic class and set the values like this,

```
APIResponse<Data> APIResponseData = new APIResponse<Data>();


APIResponseData.data.status = "Set Status";
APIResponseData.data.statusMessage = "Set Status Message";
APIResponseData.code = 1;
APIResponseData.msg = "message";
```

You can then use the APIResponseData object how you'd like.

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but hope it helps you